# Receiver class o.s.c.b.BootstrapApplicationListener$CloseContextOnFailureApplicationListener does not define or inherit an impl

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm facing this error while running the project. I'm unable to know the cause of the error and unable to find a solution online as well.
This project is running over another laptop without any error but when I extracted the **zip** and tried to run it, found it throwing error.
 Please help me figure this out. Thanks
**Error**

> Execution failed for task ':Application.main()'.
>    Process 'command '/home/jamshaid/Documents/idea-IC-192.5728.98/jbr/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**StackTrace**

```
2019-08-11 09:57:06,589 2269 [main] INFO  com.techno.homes.Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-11 09:57:06,628 2308 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$CloseContextOnFailureApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getOrder()I of interface org.springframework.core.Ordered.
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.findOrder(OrderComparator.java:142)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.findOrder(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.java:65)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:125)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:113)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.doCompare(OrderComparator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.compare(OrderComparator.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:394)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.techno.homes.Application.main(Application.java:24)
```

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
options.encoding = 'UTF-8'}

buildscript {
project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    jarName = 'recipe'
    versionName = '1.0.0'
    gradleDockerVersion = '1.2'
    swagger2version = '2.9.2'
 }

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-    plugin:${project.springBootVersion}"
    classpath "se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:${project.gradleDockerVersion}"
}
}

task createWrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '4.4.1'
}


// Used by the Docker gradle plugin, group refers to the account under which the docker image is created
group = 'com.techno.homes'
mainClassName = 'com.techno.homes.Application'
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11


repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
}

ext {
springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.SR2'
}

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.16.Final'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.4.6'
compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version: '1.3'
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-autoconfigure', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.1.8.RELEASE'
compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.4.3.Final')
compile(group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.17.Final')
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test'
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.15.0'
 compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.4'
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '2.0.1'
 compile group: 'com.spotify', name: 'docker-maven-plugin', version: '1.2.0'
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.8'
runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.46'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
testCompile group: 'com.github.tomakehurst', name: 'wiremock', version: '1.58'
testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5'


// Basic Spring boot with config client
//   compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

// Spring OAuth2 security
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")
//  compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt")
 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-jwt', version: '1.0.10.RELEASE'

  // Eureka client
  //  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka')
 compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

// Zipkin tracing
//compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zipkin', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

// Swagger for API testing
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swagger2version}")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swagger2version}")
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '5.1.5.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.3.6.RELEASE'

compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'


//camel
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-boot', version: '2.15.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-pulsar', version: '2.24.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-core', version: '2.24.1'

compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.9.3'


}


 jar {
baseName = "${project.jarName}"
version = "${project.versionName}"
enabled = true
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.techno.homes.Application'
}
}
```

**Allication**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.techno.homes.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/spring-cloud-services-connector/issues/88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Spring Boot version is too old for your Spring Cloud version:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/552

> Spring Cloud Greenwich (2.1.x) is not compatible with spring boot 2.0.x and spring framework 5.0.x. Either update spring boot or downgrade spring cloud to Finchley.

So please update Spring Boot to 2.1.x

PS: searching on 'BootstrapApplicationListener$CloseContextOnFailureApplicationListener' would have lead you there straight away :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok - did some testing here.
Created empty SpringBoot application from start.spring.io.
Imported the project into IntelliJ.

I then loaded your gradle file contents. Also started by removing all the @ imports in the main (Application) class - just kept @SpringBootApplication.
Removed all the other classes (including tests).
Had same error.
Started by removing all the gradle dependencies for Swagger and Hibernate, etc. Those are not required to get a bare-bones SpringBoot app running.
Removing this line solved to error (not throwing the error anymore):
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")

So something needs to be configured if you want to do Spring OAuth2 ... for you to find.

Suggest you add small building blocks at a time - you have a lot of stuff in the SpringBoot main app annotated. Spring will auto-configure defaults for all it can, but you might run into similar problems.
Add one annotation - write unit test class that will verify basic functionality of that specific annotation. Then enable the next one, write unit test.... unit all are working with basic test coverage.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. I'm having a problem with my laptop with this application. It was working quite fine on my friend's laptop. I just extracted the zip and tried to run it in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of spring and cloud version not compatible.

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath /> 
</parent>
```

The version of the parent should be an upgrade one or the same as cloud version.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```