# Spring Boot Migration from 1.5.2 to 2.0.3 and Java 8 to 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Thanks in advance. I am migrating My Spring boot project from 1.5.2 to 2.0.3 Release. And Migrating java 8 to java 11. So, I am getting the below error. I am trying to fix it. But, I could not the solution. Please help me. Thank you.

POM.xml

And the Error is:

```
2021-01-03 14:33:29.704 ERROR [accounts,,,] 47001 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$CloseContextOnFailureApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getOrder()' of interface org.springframework.core.Ordered.
        at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.findOrder(OrderComparator.java:142)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.findOrder(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.java:65)
        at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:125)
        at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:113)
        at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.doCompare(OrderComparator.java:82)
        at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.compare(OrderComparator.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1322)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1231)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml to your question

Comment: Did you check your dependency hierarchy, to make sure you're not also pulling in old versions of Spring?

Comment: My learnings: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/97eff450e9edbd7d006deb35f28e3fd4, https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/0aa4ee8453e897b33e2da9319ebbc717

Comment: can you please help me to find where am I going wrong? Thank you

Comment: Why are you migrating to an obsolete version of Boot 2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447553/receiver-class-o-s-c-b-bootstrapapplicationlistenerclosecontextonfailureapplica

Comment: Actually I want to migrate to Boot 2.1.x but I read in the article somewhere that we need to migrate 2.0.x before migrating to 2.1.x.

Comment: I could migrate to Spring Boot 2.1.2 RELEASE but getting another error as below.

Comment: The bean 'corsFilter', defined in class path resource, could not be registered.